# Suggested SQL formatting

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on my SQL, and I have the following statement:

```
1    SELECT c.credit_display, t.title, t.provider
2       FROM credits c
3           INNER JOIN title t 
4           ON c.vendor_id = t.vendor_id
5       WHERE c.position = 'Director' and t.provider = 'Premiere'
6           INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/file.csv'
7           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

I was wondering what the correct formatting would be with regards to tabs. What is the suggested practice for when to indent (for example, should the third line be two tabs or three?).

Comment: Do whatever is most readable. If you're working on a team project, decide on standard formatting guidelines for everyone to use. Like many (but not all) languages, indentation doesn't make a functional difference in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is all highly subjective**.

Since the `INTO OUTFILE` and `FIELDS` options belong to the entire `SELECT` statement, I probably wouldn't indent them beneath the `WHERE` clause, but rather at the leftmost position (no indentation)

Since you have multiple `WHERE` conditions, you may indent each on a new line. I would apply the same to `SELECT` columns and `FROM` tables.  The `ON` clause in the `JOIN` is indented beneath the `JOIN`ed table it applies to.

```
SELECT
   /* each column on its own line */
   /* unless it is only 1 column */
   c.credit_display, 
   t.title, 
   t.provider
FROM
   credits c
   INNER JOIN title t 
      /* ON clause indented beneath the join */
      ON c.vendor_id = t.vendor_id
WHERE 
   /* each condition on its own line */
   c.position = 'Director'
   AND t.provider = 'Premiere'
/* This apply to the entire statement so I would not indent them
INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/file.csv'
  /* You might indent this and other LINES TERMINATED BY options 
     beneath the OUTFILE line */
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Indentation is a very subjective matter, and the best thing to do is come to agreement with your team on how you are all indenting code.

Answer (score 0):

It's all personal preference (or company coding standards, depending on your environment).  I tend to write my queries like this:

```
SELECT c.credit_display, t.title, t.provider
FROM credits c
INNER JOIN title t ON c.vendor_id = t.vendor_id
WHERE c.position = 'Director' AND t.provider = 'Premiere'
INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Where each new line of the query is aligned.  Indenting depends on where it is in the code and which language is being used.  But again, it's all up to either personal preference or company standards.